# Telerik bar chart x-axis with long texts

Tags: telerik-mvc

I'm trying the telerik bar chart in my mvc application. The texts on the x-axis labels can sometimes be very long and then they overlap.
How can i solve this? can i use a tooltip for this? and how to set the tooltip text for each bar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tooltip by adding `Tooltip(true)` like so:

```
 Html.Telerik().Chart()
           .Name("chart")
           .Theme("vista")
           .Series( series => series
                        .Bar( /*data*/)                   
           .CategoryAxis( axis => axis
                    .Categories(  /*data*/)
           .Tooltip(true)
```

This will display the value of the Series (x-axis) on hover.

I know you can rotate the labels on the category axis by doing something like this:

```
.CategoryAxis( axis =>
{
    axis.Categories( /*data*/ );
    axis.Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(45));//this rotates 45 degrees (you can use whatever value you want)
}
```

but I don't think the Label method is available on the Series.  You may consider flipping the Series and the Axis (if that would still make sense for your data).  You may also consider formatting (abbreviating) the x-axis labels and adding your own legend.

Comment: Thaks for response. The thing is, im gettings the values for labels from database, if they are longer then 10 charcters, then i have to trim the values so they fit on the labels, but i want to show the whole text as tooltip, is this possible and how?